# Отобразить элемент title с помощью selenium web-driver на скриншоте

Tags: python, selenium

Имеется веб страничка.
На веб страничке есть элемент Name 
После наведения на элемент, всплывает подробная информация об элементе. К самому элементу добавляется title Name .
Для наведения на элемент использую:

```
element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('css')
    hover = ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(element).move_by_offset(9, 9)
    hover.perform()
    time.sleep(10)
```

get_attribute("title") после move_to_element(element) - выдает названия Title.

Требуется сделать скрин вмест со всплывающей подсказкой, но окно не появляется.
При постановке брекпоинта, и самостоятельном наведении на элемент, появляется.

Подскажите, как по человечески вывести это всплывающее окошко.

Answer (score 2):

Решение таково.

Дело в том, что selenium не умеет работать с элементами, которые являются частью системы. Т.е. при наведении на элемент title появлялся, в другом слое. 
Если наводить курсор средствами системы, то всплывающее окно отображается.
Следовательно нужно наводить курсор средствами системы, а не селениума.

Остается скрестить селениум и наведение системы.

Вот функция.

```
import pyautogui

def mouse_move_to_element(driver, value, isCss):
    if not isCss:
        e = driver.find_element_by_xpath(value)
    else:
        e = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(value)

    location_x = e.location.get('x', 0)
    location_y = e.location.get('y', 0)
    size_x = e.size.get('width', 0)
    size_y = e.size.get ('height', 0)

    pyautogui.moveTo(10, 133)
    pyautogui.moveRel(location_x+size_x/2, location_y+size_y/2)
    pyautogui.moveRel(-1, -1, 0.1)
```

pyautogui.moveTo(10, 133) - верхний левый угол нашего окна браузера. (пожно поиграться с опциями и настроить под себя или вовсе избавиться от зависимости)